# Intent dont workin android studio

Tags: java, android

In my Code I have the Ende function with an OnClickListner. This function need to open another screen and I watched some YouTube tutorials but if I press the button, the app crashes. I don't know what is wrong with my code. 
I used more then 1 ways to get to the other screen. It start normally but if im pressing the button it crashes it shows no crash log so I have no way to watch where the bug is.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Object TextView;

    int eggcounter;
    Button b1;








    android.widget.TextView textClicks;
    private Object SafeBrowsingResponse;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button b1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);


        eggcounter = 10;
        final ImageButton ImgButton = findViewById(R.id.eggBtn);

        ImgButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {


                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        eggcounter = eggcounter - 1;
                        updateEgg();


                        if (eggcounter < 80) {

                            ImgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg_2);

                            if (eggcounter <60){
                                ImgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg_3);

                                if (eggcounter <40) {
                                    ImgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg_4);

                                    if (eggcounter< 15) {
                                        ImgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg_5);

                                        if (eggcounter <=0 ) {
                                            b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                            ImgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg_ende);


                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }



                        }

                    }
                }
        );

        Button Ende = findViewById(R.id.b1);


        Ende.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent g  = new Intent(v.getContext(), Ende.class);
                startActivity(g);
            }
        });

    }

    public void updateEgg() {
        textClicks =  findViewById(R.id.texstScore);
        textClicks.setText(eggcounter + " ");

    }
    public void OnClick (View view)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Ende.class);

        startActivity(i);

    }
    public void ReadMe (View view)
    {
        Intent b = new Intent(this, Lesen.class);

        startActivity(b);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the crash log and more of your code

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `new Button.OnClickListener()`?

If you want to add a click listener to a `Button` you should do like this

```
Ende.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent g  = new Intent(v.getContext(), Ende.class);
        startActivity(g);
    }
});
```

Comment: It crashes again.

Comment: if there's no logcat upload the code on github or create a .zip and share on the quesiton so i can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can start activity with this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SourceActivityName.this,TargetActivityName.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

finish(); - to destroy current activity

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the intent but with how you set the `View.OnClickListener()` you should use the following code instead:

```
Ende.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        Intent g  = new Intent(this, Ende.class);
                        startActivity(g);
                    }
                }
        );
```